# What could make a pet Titan just vanish?

Tags: nethack

My player is on L27 (the first level below the Valley) and I know that my pet titan (L24 192h p AC-15) was with me when I entered. Aside from a MMF at the far side of the maze, there were no monsters that posed a threat as far as I could tell through blindfolded ESP.  The level is mapped, and I hadn't moved very far at all before killing a barrow wight.  I used my magic whistle to see if the titan wanted the sword dropped by the wight. My other pets appeared, but the titan did not. I put on my blindfold and found no trace.  Even though titans can levitate and are highly magic-resistant, I did the due diligence of checking the Valley (one level up) and the four levels below by mapping, magic whistling, and blind ESP.  No sign. I returned to the level of the disappearance to search for a death drop, or some other clue (digging walls out, detecting objects, searching, and casting light in the half of the maze that we were in. Aside from a fire trap and a few pits, I couldn't find anything to cause his vanishing, nor any of his armor/weapons I knew he was carrying.

Am I overlooking something?  Is there some other reason for the disappearance?  If it matters, the next levels down were Asmodeus, a maze, juiblex, and another maze.

Comment: I just finished digging out a larger portion of the level, and found a levelport trap Could my titan have gone up higher (to the Castle), or even further down than the three levels the wiki says is possible?

Comment: The wiki says "up at most to level one". It means all the way to dlvl 1, not up one level.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the wiki.  Found titan DL11 (went peaceful, hope I can retame).

Comment: You should answer your own question then.